# How to connect HoloLens 2 Emulator with a local UDP Sender

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

Maybe anyone can help me with this problem. I have a UDP-Sender console application, which should send udp packages to a UWP application for HoloLens2 made with unity 2019.3.4. While beeing in the Unity Editor the App receives all packages sent from the console application correctly. 
However, if I build the solution with Visual Studio and deploy it successful on the Hololens Emulator (V. 10.0.18362....) the application receives no data. 
Earlier, when I connected the Hololens2 via usb with my computer the application running on the HoloLens2-device received the data correctly but for the moment I am forced to use the emulator. Everything has to work in my local network without internet access. 
Is there a way to set up a udp connection to the Emulator via localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the problem might be. I used Datagram Socket to set up the connection between the app and the Emulator Project. 
In the Microsoft Documentation as well as in this unity question they mention that Datagram-Sockets can´t set up connections to localHost. Since I can successfully bind my socket and just don´t receive data I guess this is the problem. I will try to use the UWP share contract instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets
https://forum.unity.com/threads/uwp-for-wmr-datagramsocket-not-receiving-udp-data.586147/

Answer (score 1):

Are the console app and the emulator running on the same PC?  The emulator runs behind a NAT, so it won't be able to see traffic from other devices on your network by default.  You can, however, add a port mapping to allow select traffic into the emulator.  Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator#nat-configuration-tab for details.

Comment: Yes it runs on the same PC and I already configured the NAT to receive data from the console app and convert them to an internal port where my unity Project listens to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, but this month a new emulator was released. It matches the current HoloLens OS if your HoloLens 2 is currently updated. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator#installing-the-hololens-emulator 
This will instead be version 10.0.19041...